# cannot find package named tf

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros-indigo-base version, using ubuntu 14.2 getting error: cannot find package named tf. I have installed it but still can not import it in .py file. What should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241610/cannot-find-package-named-tf/) by [swati shirke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27205/swati-shirke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are installing ROS on a laptop or desktop (i.e. anything that isn't an embedded system) you should install the recommended "desktop-full" version rather than the "base" version (more on that [here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)). I'm not sure tf is included in the "bare" version, and if you're just starting off with ROS you probably want the "desktop-full" version anyways.

Once you install the "desktop-full" version and follow the [environment setup instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment), you should be good to go.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0